# trying to get hit detection to work for pong. left paddle won't work

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a pong game in javascript for a final project, but the hit detection doesn't work for my left paddles. the right paddle will work but the left doesn't. If i tweak the greater than less than values the ball has a seizure.

I really don't know how to fix this. please help!

```
//hit detection right paddle
if((ballinfo.x + ballinfo.size) <=(boxtwo.x)){
                if (ballinfo.y > boxtwo.y){
                    if((ballinfo.y + ballinfo.size) <= (boxtwo.y + boxtwo.height)){
                        ballinfo.velocity.x *= -1;
                        console.log("collision");
                    }
                }
            }

//hit detection left paddle
if((ballinfo.x + ballinfo.size) <=(box.x)){
                if (ballinfo.y < box.y){
                    if((ballinfo.y + ballinfo.size) <= (box.y + box.height)){
                        ballinfo.velocity.x *= -1;
                        console.log("collisionleft");
                    }
                }
            }

            ballinfo.x += ballinfo.velocity.x;
            ballinfo.y += ballinfo.velocity.y;
```

Comment: It's a bit hard to tell without knowing what these values are supposed to represent. One thing that seems strange is that the only real difference between those two sections is the comparison between ballinfo.y and box.y. I would expect the difference to involve x values.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the wrong comparison operator was inverted between your right and left.  Try changing the first 2 compare operators in the left section to see if that helps.

```
if((ballinfo.x + ballinfo.size) >=(box.x)){
            if (ballinfo.y > box.y){
```

I'm assuming the checking on y is for the paddle, so the code there should be identical between the left and right paddles (replacing the object name, of course).